UWP Canvas и TextBlock
Перетаскиваю на Canvas TextBlock и устанавливаю его в центр Canvas.
Запускаю приложение для проверки и вижу, что TextBlock появляется
не в центре а справа и снизу экрана. А в режиме проектирования он
находится в центре. Тоже самое получается и с Button.
